# XML Schema validation using xerces for Android

Tags: android, xml, validation, xsd, xerces

I am trying to validate an XML file against an XML Schema file and I have downloaded the https://code.google.com/p/xerces-for-android/ library to get XML Schema validation to work and I have created the project as a library. I am having trouble getting it to work properly for Android and I get the 'FileNotFoundException' error and if anyone can see what I am doing wrong or what I need to do to get it to work, then please can you help me.

Here is the code:

```
public void xmlValidator() throws IOException, SAXException
{
    Source schemaFile = new StreamSource(new File("device_description_schema.xsd"));
    Source xmlFile = new StreamSource(new File("device_description.xml"));
    SchemaFactory schemaFactory = new XMLSchemaFactory();
    Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(schemaFile);
    Validator validator = schema.newValidator();
    try {
      validator.validate(xmlFile);
      System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is valid");
    } catch (SAXException e) {
      System.out.println(xmlFile.getSystemId() + " is NOT valid");
      System.out.println("Reason: " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}
```

And here is the logcat errors:

```
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /device_description_schema.xsd: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:197)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:133)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:395)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(XMLErrorReporter.java:305)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.reportSchemaError(XSDHandler.java:4098)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument1(XSDHandler.java:2452)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.getSchemaDocument(XSDHandler.java:2161)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.traversers.XSDHandler.parseSchema(XSDHandler.java:558)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadSchema(XMLSchemaLoader.java:582)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:549)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaLoader.loadGrammar(XMLSchemaLoader.java:515)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.org.apache.xerces.jaxp.validation.XMLSchemaFactory.newSchema(XMLSchemaFactory.java:237)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at mf.javax.xml.validation.SchemaFactory.newSchema(SchemaFactory.java:611)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at com.example.mobileapplicationretry.generalclasses.ValidateXml.xmlValidator(ValidateXml.java:49)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at com.example.mobileapplicationretry.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-29 15:05:09.461: W/System.err(14294):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> /device_description_schema.xsd: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Please check the path of the file.

Use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to get the path of the sdcard if your file is stored here

Hope it helps

EDIT : Use `getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.filename)` to get an InputStream of a file under /res/raw

Comment: I only have the files stored in my project folder under res/raw/. I feel like I am doing the wrong thing here slightly and that it is looking for the file on the device and obviously it's not there. How should I fix this?

Comment: I have tried that and it wouldn't detect the files in the raw folder. Should I try creating the folder again or is there another way?

Comment: If you do a ctrl+space avec writing R.raw, does the file appear ?

Comment: No it doesn't appear at all. The only options that appear are 'class' and 'this'.

Comment: Try cleaning and refreshing :)

Comment: It has found them now! Do I do an InputStream for both the schema and the xml file? Or just the schema and then what else for the xml file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36516/discussion-between-james-meade-and-skaard-solo)

Answer (score 0):

For Android, you must put your files into assets directory and open the file with the Android context:

```
Context myAndroidContext;
...
final Source xsdSource = new StreamSource(myContext.getAssets().open(
                FOLDER  + File.separator + xsdFileName));
...

// FOLDER into assets if you need
```